# Get sorted folders by size when getting them from outlook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook

I use the following code to retrieve all folders from outlook :

```
 public void getFolderPath()
    {
        try
        {
            OutLook.Application oApp = new OutLook.Application();
            OutLook.NameSpace oNS = (OutLook.NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);

            foreach (MAPIFolder folder in oNS.Folders)
            {
                GetFolders(folder);
            }

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp);


        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This show me all folders from top to bottom as listed in OutLook , is there a way that i can show them or go trough them i ascending order by their size.

Something similar to :

```
foreach (MAPIFolder folder in oNS.Folders.sortbysize())
        {
            GetFolders(folder);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `Folders` collection in Outlook is not sortable.

Even if you were to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language), sorting folders on the `PR_MESSAGE_SIZE` property won't work: PST provider does not expose it, and Exchange tends to return 0 for all folders.
You can sort by the `PR_CONTENT_COUNT` property (number of messages in the folder), but not by size. The following script (Outlook VBA) uses [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) to sort the folders by `PR_CONTENT_COUNT`:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT 
set Folders = Session.Stores.DefaultStore.IPMRootFolder.Folders
Folders.MAPITable.Sort "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36020003", true
for each Folder in Folders
  Debug.print Folder.Name & " (" & Folder.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36020003") & ")"
next
```

And an even faster version (it does not open the child folders and uses `ExecSQL` method) will be

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT 
set Folders = Session.Stores.DefaultStore.IPMRootFolder.Folders
set MAPITable = Folders.MAPITable
MAPITable.Sort "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36020003", true
set Recordset = MAPITable.ExecSQL("SELECT ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3001001E"" AS PR_DISPLAY_NAME, " & _
                                  " ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36020003"" AS PR_CONTENT_COUNT " & _
                                  " from Table")
while not Recordset.EOF
    Debug.Print Recordset.Fields("PR_DISPLAY_NAME").Value & " (" & Recordset.Fields("PR_CONTENT_COUNT").Value & ")"
    Recordset.MoveNext
wend
```